# Saving a string to Bitmap to be found by an image viewer app

Tags: java, android, bitmap, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to save a string to a bitmap using the following method:

```
private void saveImage(){
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth();
    int height = display.getHeight();

    Bitmap toDisk = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(toDisk);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextSize(30);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawText("HELLO WORLD!!!", 150,150, paint);

    try {
        FileOutputStream fout;
        fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath()+"/" +System.currentTimeMillis()+".png"));
        toDisk.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fout);
        fout.flush();
        fout.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

EDIT I partially solved the problem so here is the new question:

This doesn't work on devices that do not have a file explorer app as I cannot find the image. Ideally the image should appear in the image viewer app. Instead, I have to find the image in the file system if I want to see it. And when I try to open it Android asks me to select an application to open it with.

Comment: Maybe check the external storage, if it's mounted and stuff...

Comment: Shouldn't it have to throw an exception if the external storage isn't mounted?

Comment: post full stack trace of error.

Comment: There is no error. And there is no image.

Comment: You are already said that you are getting `FileNotFoundException`.